# Oracle database connection using python is not Working

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, ubuntu-18.04, cx-oracle

I'm trying to connect to the oracle database in python using cx_Oracle. But I'm stuck with the below error.

[image]

For reference my code

```
  def runQuery(self,query):
        with cx_Oracle.connect(config.username,config.password,config.dsn,encoding=config.encoding) as connection:
            try:
                print(connection.version)
            except cx_Oracle.Error as error:
                print(error)
```

Config File

```
username = 'dummy'
password = 'dummy'
dsn = 'dummy@//localhost:1521/ORCLCDB.localdomain'
port = 1512
encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

For additional knowledge, using the docker image of the oracle database for this purpose.

May I know how can clear the issue and proceed and could someone please help to find what is missing in my implementation.

Comment: This site has many similar questions, check your `client version 32-bit or 64-bit`, check `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`...Please try the suggestions first.

Comment: My client version is 64bit . How we can check LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Echo the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable and see if it's pointing to the location where your instant client is installed. If not, export or set it based on your OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have Oracle Instant Client installed? Looks like you are using Ubuntu. For an RPM-based distro, installation would [look like this](http://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-python.html#InstantClientEnv). There are instructions out there to install Oracle Instant Client on Ubuntu as well, but perhaps you are better of putting your Python code and cx_Oracle in a container as well, as [Chris Jones explains here](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1).

Comment: I'm developing the script in ubuntu. But I need to run the script in both ubuntu and window, How can implement the oracle connection in python irrespective of the operating system

Comment: Put everything in a container. See Chris Jones' blog posts

Comment: I can't use docker in the real scenario. Used it as ease for installing the oracle DB in Linux

Comment: Then you'll need to make sure the OS in question has cx_Oracle and Oracle Instant Client installed properly. [Instructions for Windows are here](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-windows) .